# PHP to Python Server Pages, Sessions and EXEC

Tags: php, python, mod-python

I'm trying to convert this PHP to psp(python server pages). I'm at a loss with the php exec function and isset for the session variables.

```
session_start();
if(isset($_POST["var"])){
    //set session username
    $username = (string)$_POST["var"];
    $username = trim($username);
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username; //store $username
}

if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];  //store session[username] as $username
    $cmd = '/var/www/cgi-bin/resolveID.py ' .  escapeshellcmd($username); 
    $fullname = exec($cmd);
    $_SESSION['fullname'] = $fullname;

}
else{
    echo 'Your session has expired, please click <a href="https://devh.test.com/">here</a>';
    exit;
}
```

This is what i have

```
<% 
import cgitb, session
cgitb.enable()

user_session = Session.Session()
#post info
if form.getvalue('var'):
    varUsername = form.getvalue('var')
    user_session['username'] = varUsername

#session set stuff
try:
    if user_session['username']:
        #is set
        varUsername = user_session['username']
        varCMD = '/var/www/cgi-bin/resolveID.py ' + varUsername
        varFullname = subprocess.check_output(varCMD)
        user_session['fullname'] = varFullname
except:
    #not set
    req.write('Your session has expired, please click <a href="https://dev.test.com/">here</a>')
%>
```

Comment: This is what i have so far, keep getting 500s.

Answer (score 1):

I think [`subprocess.check_output()`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) is the function you are looking for:

```
fullname = subprocess.check_output(['/var/www/cgi-bin/resolveID.py', username])
```

Instead of `isset($array['key'])` you use `'key' in array` in python.

Comment: can you explain the second part of your answer. About key in array?

Comment: No dice with the subprocess.check_output